# Sum of two nested lists

Tags: python, list, nested

I have two nested lists:

```
a = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
b = [[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]
```

I want to make:

```
c = [[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
```

I have been referencing the `zip` documentation, and researching other posts, but don't really understand how they work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to do this a whole bunch, you'll be better off using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
b = [[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]

aa = np.array(a)
bb = np.array(b)
c = aa + bb
```

Working with numpy arrays will be much more efficient than repeated uses of `zip` on lists.  On top of that, numpy allows you to work with arrays much more expressively so the resulting code us usually *much* easier to read.

---

If you don't want the third party dependency, you'll need to do something a little different:

```
c = []
for a_sublist, b_sublist in zip(a, b):
    c.append([a_sublist_item + b_sublist_item for a_sublist_item, b_sublist_item in zip(a_sublist, b_sublist)])
```

Hopefully the variable names make it clear enough what it going on here, but basically, each `zip` takes the inputs and combines them (one element from each input).  We need 2 zips here -- the outermost `zip` pairs lists from `a` with lists from `b` whereas the inner `zip` pairs up individual elements from the sublists that were already paired.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll look into numpy. Indeed, this code is not easy to read. Your explanation of the two zips makes a lot of sense. Thanks for such a clear explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You may use *list comprehension* with `zip()` as:

```
>>> a = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
>>> b = [[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]
>>> [[i1+j1 for i1, j1 in zip(i,j)] for i, j in zip(a, b)]
[[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
```

More generic way is to create a function as:

```
def my_sum(*nested_lists):
    return [[sum(items) for items in zip(*zipped_list)] for zipped_list in zip(*nested_lists)]
```

which can accept any number of list. Sample run:

```
>>> a = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
>>> b = [[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]
>>> c = [[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
>>> my_sum(a, b, c)
[[6, 6, 6], [6, 6, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use python build-in function *map()* to do this.

If I have simple list a and b, I sum them as this way:

```
>>> a = [1,1,1]
>>> b = [2,2,2]
>>> map(lambda x, y: x + y, a, b)
[3, 3, 3]
```

If I have nested list a and b, I sum them as a similar way:

```
>>> a = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
>>> b = [[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]
>>> map(lambda x, y: map(lambda i, j: i + j, x, y), a, b)
[[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
```